# RabbitMQ policy synchronising of queues across cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

We have setup a RabbitMQ cluster with 3 nodes.  If an effort to have some form of load balancing, we setup the policy to only sync across 2 of the nodes:

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-2 . '{"ha-mode":"exactly","ha-params":2,"ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'
```

This works as expected when all 3 nodes are online.

When we shutdown one of the nodes (to simulate a failure) queues mastered on the failed node are still available (on the slave) but not synchronized to another node. If we manually re-apply the policy, the queues then synchronize as expected.

Should we expect that all queues be mirrored in the scenario that one node fails with this policy?

Comment: Which version are you using? I tried to create the same configuration and it works correctly. When I stop one another one is added and the messages synchronized.

Comment: @Gas Currently on 3.2.4. Started setting up cluster on 3.5.4 after I posted to see if this works differently.  Thanks

Comment: You're right @Gas, this works as expected on 3.5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as expected in RabbitMQ 3.5.4